# Assuming a symbol is between zero and one with SymPy?

Tags: python-3.6, sympy

I am doing symbolic manipulation of very large expressions in Python using SymPy.  Most of the symbols that I am manipulating represent nonnegative, real numbers, less than or equal to one.

How can I tell SymPy these assumptions? I have figured out that I can do the following when creating the symbol.

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x', real=True, nonnegative=True)
```

but I don't see how to impose the upper bound of one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the currently implemented system of assumptions does not provide a way to impose such a bound. For some purposes, it may be reasonable to introduce algebraic structure that implies the bound: for example,

```
t = sym.symbols('t', nonnegative=True)
x = t/(1+t)
```

Now SymPy knows that x is between 0 and 1:

```
>>> x < 1
True
>>> x >= 0
True
```

Whether this is helpful depends on how natural this substitution for the expressions you are working with. Another option is `x = sym.exp(-t)`

Comment: Great idea, although simplified _expressions_ will of course be given in terms of `t` rather than `x`, which is not desirable.  And awkwardly, `simplify` using `x=exp(-t)` will expand into an expression from which it cannot thereafter recognise `0<x<1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick similar in spirit to the accepted answer, but which retains the original symbol in the expression.

Consider:

```py
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, conjugate, Q

x = symbols('x', real=True, nonnegative=True)

expr = sqrt(1-x) * conjugate( sqrt(1-x) )
```

Assuming `0 <= x <= 1`, we know that `expr` would simplify to `1-x` but we cannot directly make use of this assumptiom in sympy:

```
expr.simplify()
>>> sqrt(1 - x)*conjugate(sqrt(1 - x))

expr.refine(Q.positive(1-x))
>>> sqrt(1 - x)*conjugate(sqrt(1 - x))
```

We wish to communicate to sympy that `1-x` is always positive or zero. If we could replace `1-x` with a symbol `y` declared as `nonnegative=True`, then `simplify()` could recognise `sqrt(1-x) = sqrt(y)` is real and simplify away the conjugate and product.

We can do just that, and we don't even need to use a new symbol! We substitute `x -> 1-x` so that sub-expressions `f(1-x)` become `f(x)` which can now be simplified, leveraging that their parameter is positive. Then, we restore `1-x -> x` by again substituting `x -> 1-x`.

```py
expr = expr.subs(x, 1-x).simplify().subs(x, 1-x)
>>> 1 - x
```

This seems safe; our substitution is mathematically equivalent to asserting that `x <= 1`, which coupled with our explicit sympy assumption `x >= 0`, achieves the intended bound.

We can easily extend this to simplify expressions assuming `0 <= x <= b` for a positive bound `b`:

```py
expr = expr.subs(x, b-x).simplify().subs(x, b-x)
```