# How to tell Sympy that a symbol is less than 1?

Tags: sympy

I want to define a variable that is les than 1 but greater than 0, i dont know if that can be done from the begining, i have something like this

```
delta = var(r'\delta',positive=True) # added style
```

i'm using jupyter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your definition of delta, let `n = 1/(1 + delta)` (or `delta/(1 + delta)`) and it will be as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with @smichr's answer is that your expression is recast in terms of the new symbol, which may be undesirable. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78132709/848292) where I show how to simplify sympy expressions under an assumption `0 <= x <= upper_bound`